# Why was this migrated?

Tags: discussion, migration

I disagree with the migration of my question: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/18895/learning-german-and-yiddish-at-the-same-time

In asking the question, I was hoping that readers knowledgeable about language acquisition could make plausible inferences about my situation from what is known about speakers or learners of two languages whose proximity is comparable to that of German and Yiddish. For example, if someone was aware of a study on people learning Spanish and Portuguese simultaneously, that would be highly useful. That may be better than anything I can hope for, but as I said, at minimum I am asking for plausible inferences from what is known about language acquisition.

The migration has instead narrowed the question to one about a specific pair of languages that few people are likely to have useful information on. I don't see how the German site will better be able to address the issue of what one should consider in learning two closely related languages.

Comment: Language Learning Stack Exchange, which was not yet in public beta when this question was asked, has a [tag for questions involving multiple languages](http://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiple-languages), where this question may be a good fit.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't participate in the migration but here's my take. The question you're highlighting here is different from what you asked in your original one. The questions you asked were:

> 1) How difficult is this going to be?

This is not really answerable. The best answer is "It depends". It depends on millions of things.

> 2) What can I do to make it easier? (For example, learn Yiddish with textbooks in German that draw attention to the differences?)

Asking for advice for learning languages is off topic on this site.

> 3) Would there be a big advantage in delaying learning any more Yiddish until my German is good? (In that case, I'll certainly lose what I've acquired so far.)

It depends again. Some people can do it, others can't.

---

If you want, you could ask another question with a wording like this:

> Is it objectively more difficult to learn closely related languages than languages that are less/not at all related? What is the difference, if any? Are there studies on this subject?

I think this is a much better fit than the migrated one.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I'll try again.

Comment: @user6849 No problem! Make sure it hasn't been asked already. Do a search. :D